# How to get the SHA 1 fingerprint certificate, from terminal? (without "android studio")

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, sha1, sha

I'm trying to configure the SHA-1 key for a web app in firebase. I've tried to follow different tutorials and answers, most of them presuppose that you have "androidstudio" installed or simply didn't work for me, for example:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

Is not working, because I don't have the .android dir, but even changing the directory won't work, I guess I need to generate the key before apply that command. But trying to generate the SHA ket with "keytool -genkey" or "-genkeypair" I still get some errors, like the "not such file or directory" even when the directory is there. I've tried almost everything, even I've read the oracle documentation of keytool. Thanks in advance.

pd: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth this is what i want to replicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing to do, if you already have an Android project that builds with Gradle, is to run this:

```
./gradlew signingReport
```

And that will give you the hashes for each build variant in your project.  It will even tell you which keystore file the hashes come from.